# Get easy access to peripherals using arm-none-eabi-gdb and openocd

Tags: debugging, gdb, stm32, openocd

I use `openocd`, `arm-none-eabi-gdb` and `STLinkV2-1` to debug `STM32F411CE` chip. I use also LL and CMSIS libraries. The problem is that to check the value of e.g. a pin I have to look up in the datasheet the register boundary addresses for the specific GPIO port (e.g. `0x4002 0000 - 0x4002 03FF` for `GPIOA`) and then check whats the offset for the register I want to read (e.g. `0x10` for `GPIOx_IDR`). Then to check a specific bit I have to check once more in datasheet what's the offset for it in the register and calculate from hex value the value of the bit. So for `gdb` it will be:

```
(gdb) x 0x40020010
0x40020010: 0xa8280000
```

Is there an easier approach to get the value, by typing something like that:

```
get bit value in register GPIOA IDR
```

I couldn't find anything in `openocd` datasheet or in the Internet which answers my question.

Comment: looking at the chip docs like you did is the easiest way IMO...you could take that mass of headers and write a tiny function unsigned int fun ( void ) { return(GPIOA_IDR); } compile then disassemble and it will show.  openocd is not connected to CMSIS (thankfully) it is its own deal, would be a nightmare if such a thing were to happen with all the possible chips it is able to connect to.   the telnet/gdb interfaces are documented and you can easily write your own program that interfaces them and any tables you wish to create.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found a solution.

`CMSIS` defines all the peripherals, so we can make use of it:

1. Compile the project with `-gdwarf-4 -g3` gcc flags to use preprocessor macros within `gdb`
2. Run `gdb`:

   ```
   arm-none-eabi-gdb -nw program.elf
   ```
3. Make use of CMSIS definitions: to check e.g. 3rd pin on PORTB used as input:

   ```
   (gdb) p (GPIOB->IDR & GPIO_BSRR_BS_3)
   ```